# Need data from two different actions

Tags: actions, globals

I have two functions on my functions.php

Both functions are from a plugin and I'm trying to use this variable  $answerIndex in the other action to do the if condition.

The issue is I'm trying with global variables but it's not working, am I doing something wrong?

```
add_action('quiz_completed', 'mi_ld_quiz_ert', 10, 2);
function mi_ld_quiz_ert( $quizdata, $current_user ) {
global $globalres;
    if($globalres== 0){
        do_action('ld_update_group_access', $current_user, 2, $remove = false ));
    }else{
        do_action('ld_update_group_access', $current_user, 14, $remove = false ));
    }
}

add_action('learndash_ques_single_answer_correct', 'my_ld_quiz_resp',5,5);
function my_ld_quiz_resp(  $answerIndex, $correctAnswer, $userResponse) {
  global $globalres;
  $globalres = $answerIndex; 
}
```

The action my_ld_quiz_resp runs first and then mi_ld_quiz_ert.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$globalres = '';

add_action('quiz_completed', 'mi_ld_quiz_ert', 10, 2);
function mi_ld_quiz_ert( $quizdata, $current_user ) {
  global $globalres;
  if($globalres== 0){
    do_action('ld_update_group_access', $current_user, 2, $remove = false     ));
  }
  else{
    do_action('ld_update_group_access', $current_user, 14, $remove = false ));
   }
}

add_action('learndash_ques_single_answer_correct', 'my_ld_quiz_resp',5,5);
function my_ld_quiz_resp(  $answerIndex, $correctAnswer, $userResponse) {
  global $globalres;
  $globalres = $answerIndex; 
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try your code? Can you explain what it does and where the OP was wrong?

Comment: @MarkV-2 thank you, but I tried it and it didn't work. the variable $globalres is empty in the mi_ld_quiz_ert function.